# How to toggle graph visibility with CPTLegend as button

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I would like to allow toggling on/off individual plots on my CorePlot based graph. The most reasonable way to do this I think would be to allow each Legend item to act as a button. I am not sure how to do this however as a CPTLegend is a CALayer not a UIView and also because the CPTLegend represents all of the legend items, and I would need toggle actions associated with each individual legend item managed internally by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a legend delegate to monitor for touches on the legend and respond accordingly. See the "Math Function Plot" and "Simple Pie Chart" in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

For example, here's the delegate function from the function plot example that toggles visibility of the selected plot:

```
-(void)legend:(nonnull CPTLegend *__unused)legend 
    legendEntryForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot
    wasSelectedAtIndex:(NSUInteger __unused)idx
{
    plot.hidden = !plot.hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks exactly what I need. I will try it out an accept your solution afterwards.